# Need Help Forcing SSL for Remote Desktop

Tags: ssl, certificate, tls

I have a standard windows 2008 R2 server (non-domain).
I have a web service (non-IIS) 
I have a certificate issues from "GlobalSign" that came in a .pfx file.  It's properties allow for Server Authentication and Client Authentication.
I have an RDP Service that is not using MS Terminal Services nor 'Remote Desktop Services Manager'

I was able to get the non-IIS Service to use the cert from globalsign, so that when my users go to https:\mysite.com they get the green lock, viewing the certificate all is well.

Problem is using RDP.  When I use RDP, I get a certificate warning.  When I click View Certificate, it shows a self assigned cert, we will call it servername.

So I Open MMC -Add/remove snap in 'Certificates' - 'Computer Account' - Expand Remote Desktop - Certificates.  In here, I have added globalsign certificate and it's information all looks correct.  I have deleted the 'servername' certificate from this location.

When I attempt to RDP to the server, I get the same certificate warning.  I click 'no' and do not login.  When I refresh my 'Certificates' in remote desktop, the self signed 'servername' certificate re-appears.

I have tried opening Local Computer Policy\computer configuration\administrative templates\windows components\remote desktop services\remote desktop session host\security  and setting the 'Server Authentication Certificate Template' name to my 'globalsign' certificate, no change.  I have tried changing the name to 'RemoteDesktopComputer' as found when googling my issue - no change.   Seems no matter what I try in this 'Server Auth Certificate Template" field, it doesn't matter and it will create a self assigned certificate.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be directed to the support department of the custom software product you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Is your server in setup as a Session host?  Open up the session host configuration mmc, and then go to the connection properties, and select the certificate you wish to use.

[image: session host cert settings]

While you are there you can also set your 'security layer to `SSL(TLS)` only.

Comment: Hello - Unfortunately I cannot use the Session Host.  it will conflict with the RDP software that I use and not work.  If I could find that "Certificate Auto generated" options behind the scenes I think I could make it work :)

Comment: Uhm, what?  Please explain that.  What RDP software are you using that conflicts with using the session host?

Comment: BTW, see http://serverfault.com/q/241961/984

Comment: @Zoredache [2x RAS](http://www.2x.com/ras/remote-application-server/) is building on the RDP functionality but exposing its own protocol - probably something like that.

Comment: It's Called TSPLUS.  When I try to open Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration - I get the error "The service cannot be started, either bc it is disabled or it has no enabled devices".  I was am able to open 'Remote Desktop Services Manager' but that just lists the sessions.

Comment: @the-wabbit - it is a competitor of 2x client - yes :)

Comment: So if you aren't using the built-in remote desktop services, why are you assuming that the standard certificate store would be used?  A quick Google search for `TSPLUS SSL` lead me to a document describing the creation of a **Java keystore** for this product.  http://tsplus.net/support/kb/faq.php?id=35

Comment: @the-wabbit, sure but since that is the case, that sure seems like a **critical detail to include in original question**. If a 3rd party implements the RDP protocol or something similar, then clearly can't assume that it will use the builtin Windows certificate store, or that it will automatically use a certificate based on the name.

Comment: I did follow those instructions.  That will allow the web portion (https) to use the SSL.  It doesn't have any settings for their RDP portion so I was trying to find a way to make it work.

Comment: @SSLStumped As this is a specific question regarding a rather esoteric product, you should be calling their technical support. Also, the TSPlus product site is listing "Editions" where some of them are documented *not* to support *"HTTPS/own certificates"* - so check if what you're doing is a supported configuration in your edition.

Comment: @Zoredache I know...